# Laravel 5 : Form Request based on conditional if

Tags: laravel

How I can apply conditional if in my `rules()` method in request something like this code.

```
public function rules()
{
  if($request->field1 = 'something')
  {
    return [
      'field1' => 'required',
      'field2' => 'required',
    ];
  }else if($request->field1 = 'other something')
  {
    return [
      'field1' => 'required',
      'field2' => 'required',
      'field3' => 'required',
      'field4' => 'required',
    ];
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`request()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-request) helper function, it returns the current request instance or obtains an input item as:

```
public function rules()
{
    if (request('field1') == 'something') {
        return [
            'field1' => 'required',
            'field2' => 'required',
        ];
    } else if (request('field1') == 'other something') {
        return [
            'field1' => 'required',
            'field2' => 'required',
            'field3' => 'required',
            'field4' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `FormRequest` object is an instance of the `Request`, so just use `$this` to get the value you're looking for:

```php
public function rules()
{
    if ($this->field1 == 'something') {
        return [
            'field1' => 'required',
            'field2' => 'required',
        ];
    } else if ($this->field1 == 'other something') {
        return [
            'field1' => 'required',
            'field2' => 'required',
            'field3' => 'required',
            'field4' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

Do note however that if `field1` is not set to one of those two values (or is missing completely) the code above will not be returning any rules. You *have* to accomodate for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel Build-in Validation Rules [`Required If`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-required-if) OR [`Required Unless`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-required-unless) OR [`Requred With`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#available-validation-rules) in your case